# Limit[] function returning unexpected answer

Tags: functions

I've been replicating a class handout on l'Hôpital's Rule in Mathematica.  All of the results match the professor's worksheet except this one:

```
ClearAll;
f[x_] := (1 - x + Log[x])/(1 + Cos[\[Pi]x])
Limit[f[x], x -> 1]
```

...which returns "0".  Both the worksheet and Symbolab conclude that the answer is -1/π^2.  Thoughts?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You had `πx` and it was not recognized as `Pi` times `x`. Try the following:

```
f[x_] := (1 - x + Log[x])/(1 + Cos[π x])
Limit[f[x], x -> 1]
```

[image: lim]

Comment: Thank you!  All set.

Comment: @TomBarson Glad I was able to help :-)